# How do I print output of this html transformed by xsl in another php script in some div section

Tags: php, html, xslt

I need to print the html transformed output of my php script in a div element at another php script. How do I do. I tried to do it by include but it raises xml parser error. The error it raises if I include any echo statement in the file. Here is a test file that raises error:

```
<?php
include "callHier.php";
echo'test';

print $xslt->transformToXML($save);

?>
```

erro

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://127.0.0.1/test.php
Line Number 1, Column 5:
```

Here is my output code:

```
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();
$XSL->load( 'msg.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
//print $xslt->transformToXML($save);
?>
```

It builds an unordered list which I need to display in a dive in another php script.

Comment: What's the XML parser error? It shouldn't matter where you do this transform, as long as the print command's in the right spot.

Comment: @Marc B, actually the problem is if I put anything before or after include OR print statement, it raises mxl parser error. Like the test file I added to OP, it raises error "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location: http://127.0.0.1/test.php
Line Number 1, Column 5:"

Comment: Which of these two we should consider duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340444/how-to-include-use-files-that-contain-headers-in-other-files

Comment: @Alejandro, I think they are not.This question I asked I was facing XML parser error that I included into my OP.& then it was clear that header statement was causing problem, Then I asked that. People asked then asked about example then I had to put same code there too.I think myself too on this before posting that as people answering here were not considering headers.

Comment: Where are you defining `$save`? As far as the first file's concerned, it'd be an empty/null var. And if you're outputting 'test', then  line 1/col5 is the first char AFTER 'test' that'd be output... Why would the XML parser be assuming the script's output should be a Location header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `include` this script to the page you want it to appear. Then you can echo the results at any location in the page you want.

```
<?php include "yourXslSriptHere.php"; ?>
...
<div id="theDivYouWantToWriteItTo">
<?php echo $xslt->transformToXML($save); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ioannis Karadimas, I was thinking same way & used that way as I mentioned in OP but it start raising 'xml parser error'. As its my 1st time I used xml xsl transformation so I was confused there my be some conflict in using it this way.

Comment: Are the two php scripts located in the same directory?

Comment: @XCeptable, Have you tried changing the header into `text/html`?

Comment: which header do you mean? of xsl filr? It has two headers one on top that is text/htmk & other that I send before print is header('Content-Type: application/xml');
because my xsl contains XHTML.

Comment: @ Ioannis Karadimas, no, it prints perfectly